# Connection string from SqlException "network-related or instance-specific error?"

Tags: asp.net, c#-2.0

Some of my sites are reporting the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 -
>   Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

The site switches connection string dynamically and I suspect the issue is that it is not doing this correctly. If I can extract the server name it is failing to connect to, I can investigate further.

Is there any way to do this in, say, Application_Error in the global.asax?

Comment: You'll have to add logging to your code block that initiates the connection, the global asax on error will only log the SqlException as shown above, might be worthwhile checking  the InnerException though, it might have it

Answer (score -1):

This can be caused by the SQL Server service stopping running. Open `SQL Server Configuration Manager` and restart the `SQL Server` service.